# How to add a button to custom post type's posts-page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, plugin-development, hooks, buttons

How can I add a button to a posts -page. (In this case a custom post type).

I'd like to place it next to, or near, the "Add new" button, to import content from a web service.

Answer (score 7):

You can add button via [add_meta_box](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function.

```
function add_your_meta_box(){

add_meta_box('your-metabox-id', 'Title', 'function_of_metabox', 'custom_post_type', 'side', 'high');}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_your_meta_box'); 

function function_of_metabox()
{?>
    <input type="submit" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Add New" id="add-new"/>
<?php }
```

if you add to multiple post type, you should use foreach loop.

```
function add_your_meta_box(){

  $types = array("post","page","custom_post_type");

  foreach($types as $type){

    add_meta_box('your-metabox-id', 'Title', 'function_of_metabox', $type, 'side', 'high');}

}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'add_your_meta_box');
```

Comment: That solution adds the button on the edit post -page, not the posts listing page, which was what I originally wanted. Could be an OK place to add such a button however.

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
function custom_js_to_head() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("body.post-type-YOUR-CUSTOM-POST-TYPE .wrap h1").append('<a href="index.php?param=your-action" class="page-title-action">Import from ...</a>');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_js_to_head');
```

That code (pasted to functions.php) will dynamically add new link tag after "Add new" link.

Comment: I was somewhat hoping that the use of javascript wouldn't be necessary. But if there's no hook to add buttons, and it's safe to assume .wrap h1 exists in themes... Then I guess it's acceptable.

Comment: I dont't know about any hook that can place some HTML exactly on that place. And it's based ond wp-admin HTML structure, so it won't be affected by any front-end theme change.

Comment: Very weird there is no "Wordpress way" to do that. 
Or maybe... this is the "Wordpress way"...