# How to add button to post page WordPress 5.x

Tags: custom-post-types, editor, post-editor, block-editor

How can I add a button to a posts page? what hook can be used to add a custom button

I'd like to place it next to, or near, the "Publish/update" button, or modify the publish button for triggering Pre-publish changes and export content from The new Gutenberg editor Blocks.

**other tried approach's.**

[add button to post edit page when post_status=publish](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67154/add-button-to-post-edit-page-when-post-status-publish)

[How to add a button to custom post type's posts-page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/200338/how-to-add-a-button-to-custom-post-types-posts-page)

Comment: There isn't a formal API to do this yet - https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/30901 requests one and https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/16988 discusses how some other plugins accomplish it.